# UDA-SQL-0107 A general exception has occurred during the operation "prepare". [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0121E Invalid column number

Tags: db2, cognos

I am getting this error when validating a query subject with Cognos FM 10.2.1.2 (fix pack is applied.) against an iSeries(i5) db2 database. The application servers are on linux. The FM is loaded onto Windows 7 professional. The error occurs with all query subjects, even after a clean (new) import of the tables. I am stumped as to the cause.  Has anyone come acrosss this issue? If so, can you share your resolution?  Thank you.

Comment: On your windows 7 macine (where FM is installed), have you installed db2 / iseries drivers? how do you connect to the db2? ODBC? native?  When you established the connection on the cognos server, did you test the data source? Did it successfuly connected to the db2 server?

Answer (score 0):

Root cause - DB2 using implicit hidden columns, Cognos FM doesn't see when updating QS. Short term solution, un-hide the implicit hidden columns.